# Modify script to get sheet folder ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like some help to modify this script here: [Upload multiple large files to Google Drive using Google Apps Script](https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload)

The question is the following: this script uploads to a folder within the folder defined in `const uploadParentFolderId = "1cOe4ZXjBUZHgPwADg1QRpUzcQqGxON_4";` which is in the `forms.html` file, the problem is that I intend to call this script within a spreadsheet through an `html alert` and I would like that the file was uploaded inside a folder of the spreadsheet folder, that is, the script would need to get the `ID` of the spreadsheet folder.

Javascript is a language that is a little out of my daily life, but I'm trying to learn it on my own...

If anyone can give me a light on this, it will be of great help!

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var AllFolders = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents();
var ChildFolderTest;
if (AllFolders.hasNext()) {
ChildFolderTest = AllFolders.next();
var FinalFolderID = ChildFolderTest.getId();
          }
    
    
const chunkSize = 5242880;
const uploadParentFolderId = FinalFolderID; // creates a folder inside of this folder
```

But for some reason it doesn't work, the upload doesn't start.

Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is via a [printing scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets). You can use HTML templates which will output data from your server functions and print it to the HTML file.

Based on the script you found you can first change the declaration of the folder `const` on the forms.html file:

```js
const uploadParentFolderId = <?=getParent()?>; // creates a folder inside of this folder
```

As explained in the docs, the `<?= ... ?>` tags indicate that the output from the `getParent()` function will be printed to the HTML file.

Then create `getParent()` on the Code.gs file to return the ID of the sheet's parent folder:

```
function getParent(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var id = ss.getId()
  var parent = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents().next().getId()
  return parent
}
```

Finally change the `doGet()` function on the Code.gs file to use a template instead of just printing the HTML file, this is so the `<?=?>` tags can be interpreted before outputting the page:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms.html').evaluate();
}
```

I just modified this from the script and was able to create the new folder in the same location as the Spreadsheet.

##### Reference:

- [HTML Templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/template)

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel! I tested it and it worked perfectly, I spent all day trying, but as I had no experience with this type of work between client and server, I was going around in circles.

I am also very grateful for the detailed explanation, I learned very valuable things that will be of great help in resolving other situations.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Do note that my sample is used to generate HTML the files dynamically before the page loads, while TheWizEd's sample works at runtime after the page has loaded, so learning both approaches may help you in future projects.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to get the spreadsheet folder id.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="uploadParentFolderId" type="text">
    <br>
    <input id="getFolderButton" type="button" onclick="getFolderButtonClick()" value="Get Folder">
    <script>
      function getFolderButtonClick() {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function(folder) {
              document.getElementById("uploadParentFolderId").value = folder;
            }
          ).getFolder();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function getFolder() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(spread.getId());
    let folders = file.getParents();
    return folders.next().getId();
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw "Error in test: "+err;
  }
}
```

Reference

- [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Right, the big problem is that I don't know where to implement this in the code, I also don't know if this implementation should be done in `Code.gs` or in `forms.html`... I've been trying for a while, but I still can't get it to work... I'm really a beginner in GAS applications.

Comment: To use SpreadsheetApp and DriveApp, as I have shown, this needs to be in Code.gs (the Server code) and called by [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) from forms.html within the <script> tags (the Client code).

Comment: What is causing a big confusion in my head is that in this type of work there is information on both sides, as far as I understand, if I need to fetch information from any Google App, the code has to be in Code.gs, but in this script the ID of the parent folder is placed in the .html file... what I'm not understanding is how to get the id of the spreadsheet folder and pass this information to the forms.html file... Thank you for your help and attention!

Comment: Many, many thanks for the help! Your help solved a big headache I was having, plus I learned a new way to work with this type of request. Unfortunately it is not possible to choose 2 answers, I marked Daniel's answer as a solution because it adapted a little better to the script already ready, but I reinforce that what you taught me will help a lot in my day to day.